# I can not print string that contains (0x0D) on console

Tags: java, hex, system.out

I am trying to print this String with `System.out.println()` but it did not print as I expected. I could get what I print via TCP/IP so I got the HEX stream too. I have to use this way, because if I use  `"line.separator"` the stream is refused.

I know that  `"line.separator"` contains `0x0D 0x0A`, but if I just add `0x0D` it doesn't work on console as I except. So, I am looking for another way to print it  without `"line.separator"`.

```
Character crChar = (char) Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(13));
String str1 =  "|||F"+ crChar;
System.out.println("*1*" + str1 + "*2*");
```

Output:

```
*2*
```

Hex stream:

```
7c 7c 7c 46 0d 1c 0d
```

If I change for "line.separator" it works

```
String crChar = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Output:

```
*1*|||F
*2*
```

Hex stream:

```
7c 7c 7c 46 0d 0a 1c 0d 0a
```

Comment: Well, 13 is carriage return, i.e. reset the position back to the beginning of the line.

Comment: "I am trying to print this String with System.out.println()" -> like, don't? It's technical content, it's not meant to go in a presentable text interface.